# R notebook corrupted on Windows

Tags: r, rnotebook

I have no idea how but a file I worked on just yesterday looks like this now 
[image]

I'm on a Windows 10 computer running R version 3.6.3. Any advice on how to restore the file would be appreciated.

Also the history of commands for that file appears to be corrupted and is not stored anymore.

Comment: I don't know that anybody can really help with this (though that's why they call it "learning"). Was there a power-glitch event or something that could cause file corruption? Is the file possibly compressed? (Prob not, compressed rarely looks like that.) Is there a network-share involved, or is it all local on `C:`?

Comment: Possibly a powerloss, but I had saved this file for sure, but it was open on Rstudio at the time. I had an older backup with a few less things than the up to date version, but it seems weird that it could corrupt the file from just power loss

Comment: Glad you had a backup! I definitely feel that this has everything to do with the OS and not with R, RStudio, or Jupyter notebooks, since I've not heard of this being a rampant problem. Good luck!